# Limit node resources given to an Azure Batch job or task

Tags: azure, batch-processing, azure-batch

Is there a way to limit the amount of resources given to a task execution in Azure Batch? The pool I set up is configured with a `ContainerConfiguration` (python SDK) and the tasks have `TaskContainerSettings` set.  I don't see a way to limit the resources given to the task anywhere.  I'd like to limit things like CPU cores and RAM given based off the image the task is going run.

Is it something that can be set in the `container_run_options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set options for `docker create` in that property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.taskcontainersettings.containerrunoptions?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_TaskContainerSettings_ContainerRunOptions). Please see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/ for valid options for `docker create`.

Comment: Do you know if the Batch scheduler will be able to take advantage of the unused resources? I can run some tests but I thought you might know off the top of your head.

Comment: The Azure Batch scheduler does not currently take into consideration node performance metrics when conducting scheduling. You can use the options provided to restrict your containers from starving each other, but the scheduler will schedule according to number of running tasks and either pack or spread the tasks depending on what you specify.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info.  I wonder if this is on there roadmap as I think it's an important feature that AWS Batch has?